# perl printing variables

Tags: perl, printing

The common code is :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $f = $ARGV[0];
use Bio::EnsEMBL::Registry;
use Bio::EnsEMBL::ApiVersion;

my $registry = 'Bio::EnsEMBL::Registry';
$registry->load_registry_from_db(
-host => 'ensembldb.ensembl.org',
-user => 'anonymous',
-port => '5306'
);

my $adaptor = $registry->get_adaptor( 'Homo sapiens', 'core', 'transcript' );

my $transcript =
$adaptor->fetch_by_translation_stable_id($f);
```

LAST LINE

#

For the LAST LINE, I am having trouble printing out the two values as two columns in the same line :

Attempt 1 code: print $f . $transcript->display_id. "\n";

Result : api.test.pl ENSP00000418690

ENSP00000418690ENST00000488594

Attempt 2 code :print $f, $transcript->display_id. "\n";

Result : perl api.test.pl ENSP00000418690 :

ENSP00000418690ENST00000488594

Any other attempt messes with accessing the display_id. What I want the format to be is :
ENSP00000418690   ENST00000488594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a space between the values, print a space between the values.

```
print $f, " ", $transcript->display_id, "\n";
```

The dot joins two strings into one string, which isn't necessary here, because `print` accepts a comma-separated list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention another possibility, you can two built-in perl variables.

```
{
    local $, = " ";   # Output field separator
    local $\ = "\n";  # Output record separator
    print $f, $transcript->display_id;
}
```

The output field separator is automatically printed between each argument in the list passed to `print`. The output record separator is printed after the final argument to `print`. Both are undefined by default, and interpreted to mean "don't print anything".

I declared them as local to a block as the simplest way of restricting them to the single `print` statement.